# Excel function is not working when Excel file is not open

Tags: excel, vba

The Excel `Today` function is not working when the Excel file is not open.

I am fetching a value using OLEDB, but it is giving the date which was saved before the file was closed.

Comment: Could you please explain how TODAy() is kept current on a 'Closed' workbook? Recalculation only occurs when a workbook is open in an Excel appl;iation (or panda or python  or poi, etc) object.

Comment: we set cell value as Today().can we do recalculation without opening Excel?